# Rex find and replace part of string Notepad++

Tags: regex, string, notepad++

I want to replace certain parts of a string (rows in a file) but leave the rest of that row untouched.

E.g file is

```
D00060230108733684
D00097440109639517
```

Need to be

```
D00060230018733684
D00097440019639517
```

I've tried Find `D.{7}010` Replace `D.{7}001`

All lines writes as `D.{7}plus` the rest of string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a subexpression that will match the capital D and seven subsequent digits: `(D\d{7})`

...and specify the substring (3 digits) you want to match (and change): `010`

Now you want to replace that with the matched subexpression: `\1`

...and the 3 new digits: `001`

So put this in the 'Replace' dialog

```
    Find what: (D\d{7})010
    Replace with: \1001
```

*This was tested with Notepad++ v6.9.2 using your example text.*

Comment: Wow so simple! Thanks very much for your help